# Why does initializing a string in a function doesn't work like int while debugging

Tags: c, debugging, visual-c++, assembly, reverse-engineering

So I tried debugging some simple C programs today ;

First one being

```
int main(){

 int a ,b ;
 return 0 ;

}
```

Which when de-compiled gave me

```
  push        ebp  
  mov         ebp,esp  
  sub         esp,008h
```

because I need to have 8 bytes to store a and b in the current stack frame since they are local variable !

But when I try the same with Strings say

```
int main() {

    char greeting[12] = "Pwnit2Ownit";
    return 0;
}
```

Which when de-compiled gave me

```
 push        ebp  
  mov         ebp,esp  
  sub         esp,0DCh
```

0DCh is 220 ,
But since the string is only 12 bytes long shouldn't the

> sub   esp,0DCh

be

> sub         esp,00ch

instead ?

And can anyone share some links on how the strings are stored in the memory and accessed later via assembly [preferebly instruction] , like hows the string greetings stored in memory if it's length is large since we can't store all in the stack itself

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez This is about C here, not sure the linked question helps...

Comment: The compiler is being defensive. It allocated an extra 208 bytes for your string, so that when you overrun the buffer, it won't do any real damage. I have a feeling that there's a compiler option to turn that feature off.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez C doesn't have a native String data type actually , thats more related to C++

Comment: @user3386109 Even i was thinking that , but another thought hit me - is that really it ?  How do they calculate the extra spaces ? 
like for a char it allocates cc[204 bytes] 

Any link to other  references or questions 

Thanks for the info :D

Comment: A quick search for `[c] stack guard` here on SO turned up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708568/overflowed-buffer-data-does-not-get-stored-contiguously/33708641#33708641).

Comment: What if you don't define anything? Will this stack allocation still be there? Perhaps you are not looking at the right thing...

Comment: Yes even if we don't  have char var ='a' ; instead we have just char var;
sub esp,0cch ; for both declaration and without declaration

Comment: @user3386109 Could you say whats the option to turn the buffer overflow option in vs 2015 ?

Comment: According to a comment in that thread, it's `/GS`, but I can neither confirm nor deny that.

Comment: @user3386109 Cool man , Figured it out :D 
Did some googling with your input changed some setting's now its only 12bytes are getting allocated :D

Comment: Well that's interesting... Visual Studio by default assumes that every programmer using that tool it is incompetent?

Comment: @lundin  Haha no , Buffer overflow was common back in the days when developers has no idea about security , so around 2003 they introduced this to help the developers with no idea on security to avoid these kind of bugs by default :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  @user3386109 pointed out  , The issue is to prevent overflow the default security check in visual studio is enabled ,  and it provides extra space in order to prevent overflows , so turning it off , made the compiler allocate only 12 bytes :D

To turn this security measure ( Buffer Security Checks GS)  off
Project settings ->  C/C++ -> Code generation -> security check = disable GS

Some post related to GS

http://preshing.com/20110807/the-cost-of-buffer-security-checks-in-visual-c/

Comment: Also note that if you'd written `const char *greeting = "a string literal";`, the string literal would be stored in a read-only section of your executable, and the function would only store a pointer to it on the stack.  Unless you need to modify a string, just use pointers to them, not arrays.